# how to use provider without context

Tags: flutter, provider, httpinterceptor

I am trying to call an api with the help of provider if response is 401..but provider takes a context to call a function.. in my case is there any way to call a function with out context? following is my interceptor where I want to call function

```
class ExpiredTokenRetryPolicy extends RetryPolicy {
 

  @override
  Future<bool> shouldAttemptRetryOnResponse(BaseResponse response) async {
    if (response.statusCode == 401) {
      //perform token refresh,get the new token and update it in the secure storage
       
          Provider.of<Auth>(context, listen: false).restoreAccessToken();
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

[image: you can see here that I need context to run function]

I am using provider to save response in variables therefore I cant use function directly following is my function

```
Future<void> restoreAccessToken() async {
    final url = '${Ninecabsapi().urlHost}${Ninecabsapi().login}/$sessionId';

    var response = await http.patch(
      Uri.parse(url),
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        'Authorization': token!
      },
      body: json.encode(
        {"refresh_token": refreshtoken},
      ),
    );
    var userDetails = json.decode(response.body);

    if (response.statusCode == 401) {
      print(userDetails['messages']);
    }

    print(userDetails);
    sessionId = userDetails['data']['session_id'];
    accessToken = userDetails['data']['access_token'];
    accessTokenExpiryDate = DateTime.now().add(
      Duration(seconds: userDetails['data']['access_token_expiry']),
    );
    refreshToken = userDetails['data']['refresh_token'];
    refreshTokenExpiryDate = DateTime.now().add(
      Duration(seconds: userDetails['data']['refresh_token_expiry']),
    );

    print(userDetails);

    notifyListeners();
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final userData = json.encode({
      'sessionId': sessionId,
      'refreshToken': refreshToken,
      'refreshExpiry': refreshTokenExpiryDate!.toIso8601String(),
      'accessToken': accessToken,
      'accessTokenExpiry': accessTokenExpiryDate!.toIso8601String()
    });

    prefs.setString('userData', userData);
    reset();
  }
```

Comment: How are the providers being created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the provider takes the `context` because it use that to find the correct (closest) instance of your `Auth` class.

Comment: then how to call that function

Comment: It's like, how to paint with black color, if you only have pink color?

Comment: Perhaps the caller of `shouldAttemptRetryOnResponse()`  can use the return value to call that method on the Provider.

Comment: I am returning false in shouldAttemptRetryOnResponse() in case of I occurred 401 response then only that function will run

Comment: So the method that is CALLING `shouldAttemptRetryOnResponse()` could do something like `if (!shouldAttemptRetryOnResponse(response)) Provider.of.....restoreAcc....`

Comment: but the retry should happen if I get response 401

Comment: Well then you have to refactor how you do the things. Either way, you cannot find the Provider without a context.

Comment: temporary I had solved by getting context through constructor eg....class ExpiredTokenRetryPolicy extends RetryPolicy {
  BuildContext context;
  ExpiredTokenRetryPolicy(this.context);